# Modifying a static variable in non-synchronized static method, is there a danger to thread safety?

Tags: java

I have a class with a static method modifying a static variable as follows, does this method needs to be synchonized for thread safe operations ?

```
public final class IdManager {

    private static int noOfIdsInReserveCurrently = 100;   
    private static final AtomicInteger allotedUserIdsCount; 

    public static int getNewId(){
         noOfIdsInReserveCurrently--;
         ....
         return allotedUserIdsCount.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Should this method have been synchronized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it's certainly not safe as it is. Two threads could both read the value, but decrement their local copy, then both write. Badness.

You *could* synchronize it (and all other aspects to the variable) - but it would be better to use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) which is designed for exactly this sort of thing. That's fine if the *only* shared state you're modifying is that one value; if you're trying to modify more shared state atomically (e.g. some "next ID" counter as well as the number of outstanding IDs) then you would need to *either* thing really, really carefully about the various interleavings, *or* use a synchronized block instead.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg: What do you mean by "threads exist in another class"? My point is that if two threads both read 100, decrement, then write 99 back then there would have been two *logical* decrements, but the overall result would be incorrect (99 instead of 98).

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks, as you  guessed correctly I have also been using another AtomicInteger object within the same class(updated in my ques.), so there is more than that shared state, (your 2nd option is not quite clear), would it be better to make this method synchronized or should I rather make the `noOfIdsInReserveCurrently`, an `AtomicInteger` ?

Comment: @user: I don't know - we'd need more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: In that case, when I am unsure, making the method synchronized  would be a more *safer* option, right ?

Comment: @user: Yes. Although you'll need to look at anywhere else you access that shared state too.

Comment: so, all methods using/modifying shared state must be synchronized ?

Comment: @user: That's a bit of a simplification, but it's a good starting point. I would personally *not* just make the method synchronized though - that effectively exposes your lock, so other code might use the same lock. Instead, have a private final variable (static if you're protecting static variables) and synchronize on that instead.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Agreed, although I'm not *totally* anti-statics. Just most of the time...